# CKFinder - Image cutting to specified dimensions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, ckfinder

When I upload a picture in CKFinder I wish this image to be `830x421px`. But for some reason, the image is not cut to those dimensions.. Instead either the height or the width is automatically made `830px` or `421px`... So the question is: How can I make CKFinder cut the image to those sizes, instead resizing...? There seems to be some kind of aspect-ratio in place that I cannot find/locate?

```
$config['images'] = array(
    'maxWidth'  => 830,
    'maxHeight' => 421,
    'quality'   => 80,
    'sizes' => array(
        'small'  => array('width' => 182, 'height' => 120, 'quality' => 80),
        'medium' => array('width' => 341, 'height' => 225, 'quality' => 80),
        'large'  => array('width' => 830, 'height' => 421, 'quality' => 80)
    )
);
```

Comment: The title says 'CkFinger', do you mean CKFinder?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\Image.php` you will see that `resize` method (for resizing images of course), actually has hardcoded call to `calculateAspectRatio` method (around line 549). It seems that you were right and there really is an internal aspect-ratio. I cannot also see any way to disable it from outside unfortunately.